# How can I display text when a button is pressed? SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

```
@State var email: String = ""
     var body: some View {
        TextField("emailaddress@gmail.com", text: $email)
        Button {
                     
                } label: {
                    Text("Send verification code")
                }

}
```

I am trying to make a button called "send verification code" so that if users input something into the text field and press the button, then the code returns the text  "Verification code sent".

(sorry I am a beginner)

Comment: There is an article about that: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-show-an-alert

Answer (score 1):

You can conditionally show the button or a simple `Text`.

The button action toggles a boolean flag which swaps the views.

```
@State private var email = ""
@State private var confirm = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("emailaddress@gmail.com", text: $email)
        if confirm {
            Text("Verification code sent")
                .foregroundColor(.green)
        } else {
            Button(action: submit) {
                Text("Send verification code")
            }
        }
    }
}

func submit() {
    withAnimation {
        confirm = true
    }
}
```

Alternatively use the button to display the confirmation text and disable user interaction

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        TextField("emailaddress@gmail.com", text: $email)
        Button(action: submit) {
            Text(confirm ? "Verification code sent" : "Send verification code")
        }
        .tint(confirm ? .green : .blue)
        .allowsHitTesting(!confirm)
    }
}
```